# Interpretation of Mantel correlograms

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, spatial

i checked the presence of spatial autocorrelation in the abundance of species living in 10x10m plots, 60 samples per plot.
I did vegan's correlog function with default bins (12 distance classes ~ each encompassing about 1.30m in my plot). I detrended my data for x,y coordinates and calculated the correlograms with spearman and pearson correlation procedures, adjusted for multiple testing with FDR.

I have difficulties interpreting the outcomes.

Here are two plots, same site, pearson vs. spearman. Each correlogram represents a species (sequence is the same), filled boxes represent a lag bin at which autocorrelation is significant.

[image: Pearson]

[image: Spearman]

1. I understand that Spearman is more relaxed in terms of data normality requirements. Most of my species data seem to follow Poisson/negative binomial distributions though, when modelling species outcomes, so i wonder if Spearman really is the best thing here, since a) the correlograms are similar, but the p-values are very different between the two.
2. Given the really low Mantel coefficients, even if there is significant autocorrelation at some scales, does it affect my hypothesis test, since the correlation seems really weak? How do i interpret a significant non-random spatial process with a mantel coefficient of 0.08?!
3. Here is another plot, another site, same species.
   [image: site2]

Here the spatial organisation is less pronounced, and partially inverted (species 1, top left). Now, if i want to test for significant differences between the two sites, i guess i need to correct for reduced degree of freedoms, but are there any tests that takes into account different degrees of spatial autocorrelation for the two populations to check?

´Thank you very much!